# Upgrading Ghostscript from v9.07 to 9.22

Tags: php, linux, ghostscript

My server is CentOS, and I am trying to use this library via composer:

https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib

However I am getting the following error message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Your version of GhostScript 9.07 is not compatible with the library`

How do I update the version of Ghostscript on the server so that I can use it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if CentOS has a newer package (probably not), you can try the pre-built binary available from ghostscript.com. If neither is succesful you will need to build Ghostscript from source.

To do that you will need a working C compiler (gcc) and autotools installed.